# Upload file using webclient: exception file not found

Tags: c#, webclient, file-not-found

I am trying to upload an excel file using webclient:

```
using (var client = new WebClient()) {
  client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(myname, mypassword);
  byte[] responseArray = client.UploadFile(
      newUri("https://www.syros.nl/prive/excel/newexcelfile.xlsx";), "POST", @"C:/Temp/~myfile.xslx");
}
```

Whatever I try, I keep getting an webexception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll An unhandled exception of type System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll An exception occurred during a WebClient request.
```

and an inner exception:

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Temp\~myfile.xslx
```

I googled this extensively, but no one seems to have this problem.
Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong? The file is definitely present.

I tried different locations for the file, different names (with/without ~), even other/wrong credentials.

Comment: First, close the file, and then try without `~` Tilda sign

Comment: I did try that, no result.

Comment: Are you sure the extension is not a typo? Because if it's an Excel sheet, the extension should be **xlsx**.

Comment: And this took me several days! A typo. Thank you, thank you! Problem solved.